# Overlay button not clickable/pressable.

Tags: ios, overlay, uitoolbar

I have overlaid a done button on a UIToolBar overlay. The done button appears on my toolbar but it's not clickable. In fact when I touch it shows no change. Obviously the doneButton is not receiving the action. My question is why and how do I rectify this? What should I replace my faulty code with?

Here is where I've set my overlay.

```
- (UIView*)CommomOverlay  {
    //Main overlay(not pertinent in this question)
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,420)];
    UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,420)];
    [FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newGraphicOverlay.png"]];

    //Toolbar overlay
    UIToolbar *myToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 428, 320, 50)];
    [myToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

    //Done button overlay
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                        target:self
                                                        action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];

    [myToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: doneButton, nil] animated:YES];

    [FrameImg addSubview:myToolBar];
    [view addSubview:FrameImg];
    return view;
}
```

Here is my doneButton pressed methodology I've used. when clicked done, the view is supposed to revert to another screen for which the .h/.m are in the name of SecondViewController.

```
-(void)doneButtonPressed {

    SecondViewController *screen = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil
    bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];
}
```

Everything appears perfect to me, but it's needless to say it isn't. I understand this appears to be a frequently asked question, but nothing i've searched is about a button's disability to function on *an overlay*. Please do discuss not only the correction part, but also the *why* part.

Comment: have you had a look at this answer for both the correction and they why?  *http://stackoverflow.com/a/2476310/774691*  i ask because i don't know whether or not your attempt to do the above is happening in a way that should allow the toobarItems to be set.

Answer (score 0):

can you just check if this thing works by doing the following..

```
FrameImg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Am not sure if this would help.

Comment: First of all, where would I add this?

Comment: UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,420)];
[FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newGraphicOverlay.png"]];
FrameImg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: No luck with that attempt. What I don't understand is why is the statement involving FrameImg? It's my doneButton that needs to acknowledge user interaction. It's not acknowledging the fact that I gave it an action command at all.

Comment: I asked this to try because myToolbar is a subview of FrameImg. So I thought that could prevent the tool bar items from getting the event.